# Save data in the folder as dat.file using matlab

Tags: matlab, save, directory

I made a filter script in Matlab. I cannot save the output of my sequential file as dat. files in folder. The error message is “error using save. Filename is too long”. Please, could someone indicate me the problem? Thanks Bruno

```
%Filtering EMG data
%%Load EMG file data
directory_name=uigetdir(pwd,'Select data directory');
directory_name=([directory_name '\']);
% directory_save=uigetdir(pwd,'Select save directory');
% directory_save=([directory_save '\']);
disp(directory_name)
mkdir(directory_name,'FilterHere');
directory_save=([directory_name,'FilterHere\']);

files=dir([directory_name,'*.dat']);

if isempty(files)
msgbox('No raw files in this directory');
end
counter = 0;

for i_files=1:length(files);
filename=files(i_files).name;
[path,filename,ext] = fileparts(filename);
file = fullfile(directory_name,[filename,'.dat']);

counter = counter + 1;
disp([filename,'(',num2str(i_files),'of', num2str(length(files)), ')'])
i_u=(strfind(filename,'_'))-1;
numbers=dlmread(file);
data=numbers(:,1);
end
FileNum=1:i_files;
for  filtLow = 10;
filtHigh = 500;
Fs = 2000;
[b, a] = butter(1, [filtLow/(Fs/2), filtHigh/(Fs/2)]);
Filter = (filtfilt(b, a,data))';

dimstr=num2str(Filter);

save_data=fullfile(directory_save,[filename,'_',dimstr,'dat']);
save(save_data,'Filter', '-ASCII');
end
```

Comment: The problem is your filename is too long. I'm guessing it's because you're putting your filtered data array, `dimstr`, into your filename with the `fullfile` call.

Comment: As a general tip, use [MATLAB's debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-242) to stop execution when there's an error in order to examine your workspace contents.

Comment: add 'disp(save_data)' before the 'save' command and check if teh variable contains the value which you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your helps.
I used dbstop if error to reveal such problem immediately. 
The script is working but is saving only the last file from the folder. I want the script to save the enter file in the folder. 
save_data=fullfile(directory_save,[filename,'_','dat']);
disp(save_data)
save(save_data,'Filter', '-ASCII');
Please, could someone indicate me the problem? Thanks Bruno
Thanks 
Bruno

Comment: @user3209872 your filename iteration and data saving are executing in separate loops, you need to combine them.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. How I combine the filename iteration and data saving?

Comment: @user3209872 put them in the same loop

Comment: @excaza Thanks again for your response. How I can put the filename and the data saving  in the same loop? Please, give me an example.